# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: _UIManager

Tags: android, react-native

First, I am not good at English. I'm sorry.

I get the following error on every touch event

All that has been modified is to install the react-native-scroll-menu package.

I deleted node_modules and installed a new one, but the error still occurs.

I can't find this case even after searching, please tell me where the error is coming from

This error only occurs on Android.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs5Hp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNx9W.png)

Answer (score 3):

We ran into this problem and only found your posted question, and we've managed to solve it for us but the solution may very well not work for you. (But better to post it in case it helps someone).

Our issue was caused by a babel plugin since we were using a third party service called FullStory.

Again it seems unlikely you're using this plugin, however commenting out the following two lines from our babel.config.js and doing a yarn start --reset-cache got rid of the error for us.

```
'@fullstory/react-native',
['@fullstory/annotate-react', { native: true }],
```

Comment: Unlikely as it sounds, this was exactly my problem. Thanks!

Comment: same problem. so you refuse fullstory in your application? no chance to make it working? did you catch this error in production? thanks for replying!